# DNN Session Variable Issues

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin, dotnetnuke-module

I am developing skin in DNN 6.02.04. In my insidepage.ascx page how to handle the session variable?.Without creating usercontrol or module how  can i set session variable?.
For Example
 1st time if anyone went to this webpage  http://www.solodyn.com/FORPHYSICIANS.aspx you get one dialogue box .In that dialogue box one button was there. if i click that button " i am healthcare professional". they set session not getting the dialogue box until my session close. In my developement website every page load i am getting that dailogue box again and again. How to use session variable in DNN Skin pages?

Thanks & Regards
Gopinath.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session is typically not recommended for use within DNN environments. I would set a cookie and then in the Skin file you could add logic that reads from the cookie using inline code in the ASCX for the skin.